# Visual Workflow to VisualForce - FlowVariable

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, metadata-api, visual-workflow

I'm trying to pass a sObject Collection variable set in a Flow to a VisualForce page.  I've set the variable type in the flow to Input/Output, as listed in the VF Developer Guide, but I dont understand how to carry the 2nd requirement which states, "The isOutput field on the FlowVariable in the Metadata API"

Can someone help me understand what that means and how to do it?

[image]

Comment: That's not a second requirement :). That's a different way to set the flow variable to allow output. The metadata api allows you to use code to change a visualflow. It is unlikely you are doing that. To be fair, that text does allow for multiple interpretations.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Lemme put that into an answer so we can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a second requirement :). That's a different way to set the flow variable to allow output. The metadata api allows you to use code to change a visualflow. It is unlikely you are doing that. To be fair, that text does allow for multiple interpretations.